# Compare what records are not in a table from different data base

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two data base named:
MEX
USA

both containg a table named: BOM,
I would like to compare these two tables to know what records (Column Named IDBOM) are not on USA data base.

Can you publish the Query please?

Comment: Do the databases have access to each other? Say with a DBLINK?

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is Oracle.

```
select field1, field2, field3
from tableA
MINUS
select field1, field2, field3
from tableB
```

will show you rows in tableA that are not in tableB based on these fields.

You can go across a dblink if needed (...from tableB@someLink)